# Is Throwing Exception to forcefully coming out of recursion efficient?

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

Following is just pseudo code.

```
  function x(node){
    if(node.val == 42) 
       return true; // What if I throw an exception here ?
    val1 = node.left ? x(node.left) : false ;
    val2 = node.right ? x(node.right): false; 
    return val1 || val2 ;
 }
```

Lets say I'm trying to find 42 in a tree.  With the above code, if I return a valid value, it will bubble up to the entire recursion chain and then finally return.

My assumption is if I just throw an exception instead of returning true at line 3, it will not actually bubble up through the recursion chain and directly return to the caller.

Is it a good practice to just throw an Exception to break the entire chain. Cause let s say at `line 4`, it did find 42 in some nested stack, and it will still pursue the recursion at `line 5`. If I just throw an exception at `line 3`, we can avoid that unnecessary computation.

**Question is more of a compiler internal, If I just throw an unhandled exception, will it still bubble up to the recursion stack(which makes this approach pointless) or directly return to Program counter of parent call.**

Comment: A student asked me this .. And this question rattled me.

Comment: It would be useful if you could describe why *you* think it's a good idea. I don't see anything good about it so it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: Exceptions should be used to handle "exceptional" scenarios, so controlling flow with them is not a good idea.  Normally, a more elegant solution is available. Can you post some code to consider?

Comment: This is my go-to resource whenever this comes up: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225. NB also the expensive "bit" about throwing is the native fillInStackTrace() being called, so try to avoid that if you _do_ want to break out like this.

Comment: why would you need to throw at all? Just return when you find "a valid result" and you never recurse too much. That's the whole point: you return through _exactly the same number of stack pushes as a return_

Comment: To avoid going down the right subtree after you've found it in the left subtree, a simple 'if' will suffice.

Comment: I know in this case I can avoid the right subtree call by checking the variable . But In many cases situation is not that simple . So even if it's an anti pattern , its programetically very efficient right ?

Comment: @NotaJD if Thow works as GOTO , then this approach will surely more efficient cause , even if we check `val1` before right recursion , it will still have to pop all the millions entries from stack (let say recursion is million level deep) before returning me the actula result .

Comment: @sapy practically speaking though, the JITter is going to make that evaluation lazy and inline val1 and val2 I should imagine. Worth profiling or seeing what the JVM does

Comment: Have you considered `return`? `throw` does not 'work as GOTO'. Just consider all the extra semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend throwing exceptions to break the recursion chain for a few different reasons.

- **Efficiency**. Throwing an exception is, generally speaking, much slower than returning from a function. Specifically, when an exception is thrown, the runtime needs to populate the exception with the current stack trace, needs to look to see which handler to invoke, needs to search for `finally` blocks to execute or `try`-with-resources statements, tracking object references for garbage collection purposes, etc. That still requires walking the call stack, the same way that returning a value up the call chain would, and it's almost certainly not going to be any faster than the more standard approach.
- **Usability**. If you throw an exception to abort the recursive chain, then whoever calls your function needs to write code that reacts to that exception. This means that instead of doing something like writing `if (myCall()) {...}`, they need to have separate branches, one for where the call returns a value normally and one for the case where it throws. If they forget to do this, the code at runtime might appear to be failing due to an exception when in fact it's actually behaving as expected. Making things worse, you actually would be *inverting* the normal use of exceptions. If your code throws an exception when it *succeeds* and returns a value when it *fails*, whoever reads your code is going to probably go "huh?" at least once before figuring out what you meant.
- **Clarity**. Exceptions are supposed to be used for situations that are, well, exceptional! The exception mechanism is designed to report back information in cases where there's simply no feasible way to return a value. Repurposing the exception system to handle regular control flow makes the code harder to read and maintain, and violates the Principle of Least Surprise.

Although your original question was mostly about the efficiency point, I'd argue that the other two points - usability and clarity - still strongly weigh in favor of not doing things this way.

Comment: Ur efficiency point if true ends the argument. If compiler still need to traverse the entire stack trace , then this approach indeed doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sapy I'd argue that even if it were more efficient, you'd still need to overcome the other hurdles in some way. Lots of modifications to code to improve efficiency hinder readability, and so there would still be a cost-benefit analysis to make.